# increase size of search terms in a magento site by applying css class-name

Tags: css, magento

on top of the site, you can see "computer, camera ,etc..."

I want to apply css class and increase the font-size of those texts.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And what didn't work as expected?

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, i got an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give class to that tags and apply font css.